# Trying to make a find and update function for Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, pivot-table, cell-format

I tried to use a VBA code in SharePoint and it did not work. I also tried using the workaround of power automate desktop but my work does not allow the desktop version because of I.T protections...

My question is can someone provide an in-cell function that will allow me to search data in column "B" which would pull information from columns "E,F,G,H". after, I can update those columns in the same area and save it?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @spikey_richie, yes I am sorry, I am speaking about excel online

Comment: A relatively minor thing, but putting the question BEFORE the list of things you tried will make this easier to read and follow. Also, please show us the code you've tried. This is not a script-writing service, and so simply asking this site to "provide" code is usually not effective. Instead: show us what you have tried, show us the code, and we then we may be able to present fixes to that code. Use the EDIT button to add this info to your question body. Do not simply add it as comments down here. It is good for you that your question gets better, because a better question means better answer

Comment: VBA code in SharePoint? Did you mean Excel online?

Comment: @Aaron is there a sample data/method for others to replicate the `to search data in column "B" which would pull information from columns "E,F,G,H"` situation/case in our own excel online sheets ? and.. whats is the content of the cells (string/numbers) ?

Comment: I am sorry for the confusion everyone and I appreciate you all trying to help
@p._phidot_ I would have all the information I am trying to pull on the same excel online sheet
Column B = County
Column E,F,G,H = Dollar rate
So the in cell function would use all the data in column B "searching by county" and will pull up the rows associated with Columns E,F,G, and H. once those rows are identified I would like to be able to update the dollar rates so I do not have to search each one because each county have more than 10 zip codes in it.

Comment: @Lee, yes Excel Online, thank you for the correction.

Comment: You'll need to convert your vba to office script for it to work with excel online. I'm not sure if there are tenancy requirements. Based on you comments you might be able to use a multicriteria filter formula to get results in each of your column and not have to do any manual "update [of] the dollar rates".

Comment: How do I covert VBA to office script? is there a converter or do I have to learn office script as well?